# How to make multiple filters in listview flutter

Tags: flutter

I try to make  multiple filters in listview. I get the data from api then filters this data in listview. Now my problem I can make filter to one option but I don't know how I can make it multiple filters by more then one option.

Page code now:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;


Future main() async {runApp(testpage(),);
}

class testpage extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _testpageState createState() => _testpageState();
}

class _testpageState extends State<testpage> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    getData();
    super.initState();
  }

  List listsearch = [];
  List ? datas;

  Future<String> getData() async {
    var response = await http.get(
        Uri.parse("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments"),
        headers: {
          "Accept": "application/json"
        }
    );
    this.setState(() {
      datas = json.decode(response.body);
    });
    for (int i = 0; i < datas!.length; i++) {
      listsearch.add(datas![i]['name'].toString()+ ':' + datas![i]['email'].toString() );
      print(listsearch.toString());

    }

    return "Success!";
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _filteredList =
        listsearch.where((jsonList) => jsonList.startsWith('id')

        ).toList();

    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: ListView(children: [
          ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: _filteredList.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                return ListTile(
                  leading: Icon(Icons.search),
                  title: Text(_filteredList[i].toString()),

                );
              })
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

As you can see in above code I try to make filter for two option name and email and now I can make one option title:

```
  final _filteredList =
        listsearch.where((jsonList) => jsonList.startsWith('id') 

        ).toList();
```

So how I can filter title and body also and at the end show data in listview based on those two options filtering together.

Code from Print data:

```
[id labore ex et quam laborum:Eliseo@gardner.biz]
```

Anyone can help me.
thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you can set more than one condition in the `where` method

let's say I have this list :

```
List<int> intList = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
```

I want to filter it to numbers that are even but not 2.
I can write :

```
List<int> filteredList = intList.where((number) => number % 2 == 0 && number != 2).toList();
```

this will result :

```
List<int> filteredList = [4, 5, 6];
```

Comment: Hi Gwhyyy I try to make like that :  final _filteredList =
        listsearch.where((jsonList) => jsonList.startsWith('2') && jsonList.startsWith('blue')

        ).toList(); / but that not work with me

Comment: can you put a sample of an entry of the listsearch list, so I can make it work

Comment: Yes, of course, I updated my question and made it work online, ready for testing and add some data from print